# Refine an algorithm to locate the extrema of an object represented by a 2-d matrix of zeros and ones

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, edge-detection

Note: Not looking for code here, just an algorithm as I am stumped not on implementing a solution to this problem but on finding out what the solution is.

I have a large 2-d array that I created from an image that is composed of zeros and ones; the ones represent black pixels and vice versa. The background is white and the picture contains a number of irregularly shaped black objects. I have already written code to detect the edges of these objects, so assume that this 2-d array only contains the edges of these objects as that processing step is already complete

I am trying to create an algorithm that is able to find the four extrema for each of these objects: the highest y, the lowest y, the greatest x, and the lowest x.

The best I have right now in pseudocode is this:

```
Initialize array = aforementioned array
Initialize temporary_coord_store=[]
Initialize coordinates=where value in array equals one
Initialize extrema=[]

Define coordinate_recurs(coordinates):
     Initialize x = first value in coordinates
     append x to temporary_coord_store
     loop while the following if statement evaluates true:
          if the value in array at an index equal to any neighbors of any coordinate in coordinates equals 1:
               append all neighbors to temporary_coord_store
     append to extrema the extreme x and y values in temporary coordinate store
     set all values in array at indexes equal to any values in temporary coordinate store=zero
     set coordinates=where value in array equals one
     if any value in coordinates equals one:
          call method coordinate_recurs(coordinates)

call method coordinate_recurs(coordinates)
```

However I feel like there has to be a more efficient and algorithm that can be devised since this basically looks at all nonwhite array values. Does anyone see a place where I can shave some time off with this pseudocode? Apologies if this is posted in the wrong channel of stack exchange; if it is please let me know so I can repost it in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt the standard [Connected-Component Labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) algorithm and just consider extending the current extrema in the appropriate direction when you visit a neighbor. For example, if you find a neighbor of the current cell to the east then you only have to consider increasing the maximum x value.

To simplify things I'm assuming your boundaries are 4-connected. I also ignore the issue of determining whether neighbors are valid, i.e. within the image.

```
image[][]   // array containing 0|1
visited[][] // boolean
queue[]     // struct to hold coordinates to be processed
extrema[]   // array of object extrema
id = 0      // current object id

for y = 0 to image.height-1
  for x = 0 to image.width-1
    if image[x][y] == 1 and visited[x][y] == false
      // new object/component
      id = id + 1
      extrema[id] = (x,y)
      queue.add(x,y)
      visited[x][y] = true
      while queue not empty
        p = queue.remove()
        // Check East
        if image[x+1][y] == 1 and visited[x+1][y] == false
          queue.add(p.x+1, p.y)
          visited[p.x+1][p.y] = true
          if x+1 > extrema[id].maxX 
            extrema[id].maxX = x+1
        // Consider North, South, West...
```